# Getting key error while using lambda function

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, aws-api-gateway

I am getting this error :

```
KeyError: 'Ítem' Traceback (most recent call last) when I am writing the code `response['Ítem']` where response is equal to
 {'Item': {'partner_id': '1002'}, 'ResponseMetadata': {'RequestId': 'IBKSRRDTFDLT6V7KI06PNGJA2FVV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJG', 'HTTPStatusCode': 200, 'HTTPHeaders': {'server': 'Server', 'date': 'Mon, 21 Feb 2022 14:52:36 GMT', 'content-type': 'application/x-amz-json-1.0', 'content-length': '36', 'connection': 'keep-alive', 'x-amzn-requestid': 'IBKSRRDTFDLT6V7KI06PNGJA2FVV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJG', 'x-amz-crc32': '311453952'}, 'RetryAttempts': 0}}
```

so why I am getting the error when I try to access 'Item'.

The whole code of the function is:

```
def getPartner(partner_id):
    response = table.get_item(
        Key={
            'partner_id': partner_id
        }
    )
    return buildResponse(200,response['Ítem'])
```

Comment: `'Ítem'` is not `'Item'`

Comment: ``return buildResponse(200,response['Item'])``

Comment: Item is what you need - not Ítem

Answer (score -1):

Since python is a case `sensitive` programming language, `Item` and `Ítem` are **not** same values.

Comment: This has nothing to do with casing. `Í` is the same case as `I`. It's just not the same letter

Comment: I was trying to say something like this `print("Ítem"!="Item")` Output:`True`